# How would I look up an entire column by name and add that data to another table?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

In KQL, given:

```
let A = datatable(XName:string, YName:string) [
"XData", "YData1",
"XData", "YData2",
];
let B = datatable(XData:double, YData1:double, YData2:double) [
0.0, 1.0, 2.0,
0.1, 1.1, 2.1,
0.2, 1.2, 2.2
];
```

How would I extend A such that the contents of the new column are a list of the values in the column in B specified by `YName`? So, given the example show above, the desired output is:

```
let DesiredOutput = datatable(XName:string, YName:string, YValues:dynamic) [
"XData", "YData1", dynamic([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]),
"XData", "YData2",  dynamic([2.0, 2.1, 2.2]),
];
```

In essence, I'm trying to use data from A to look up an entire column of B. Is there a way of wrangling KQL to do so?

---

```
let A = datatable(XName:string, YName:string) [
"XData", "YData1",
"XData", "YData2",
];
let B = datatable(XData:double, YData1:double, YData2:double) [
0.0, 1.0, 2.0,
0.1, 1.1, 2.1,
0.2, 1.2, 2.2
];

// This doesn't work because the inner statement can't access YName, but something like this, presumably.
A
| extend YValues = toscalar(
    make_list_with_nulls(column_ifexists(YName[row_number() - 1], FallbackColumnOrSomething))
)

let DesiredOutput = datatable(XName:string, YName:string, YValues:dynamic) [
"XData", "YData1", dynamic([1.0, 1.1, 1.2]),
"XData", "YData2",  dynamic([2.0, 2.1, 2.2]),
];
// A == DesiredOutput
```

Comment: It's a little unclear for me sorry, but what lookup are you trying to do?  ie how does the data in B correspond to A?

Comment: I'm trying to look up the entire column in B, based on the name of the column, which is stored as a value in A. So, in `DesiredOutput`, the first record specifies `YData1` and gets all the data from the `B.YData1` column, and the second record specifies `YData2` and gets all the data from the `B.YData2` column.

I'm aware that this is a pretty weird thing to want to do. It has to do with trying to use ADE's plotly graphing system without the python plugin being available.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following if your data is consistently structured enough.

```
let A = datatable(XName:string, YName:string) [
"XData", "YData1",
"XData", "YData2",
];
let B = datatable(XData:double, YData1:double, YData2:double) [
0.0, 1.0, 2.0,
0.1, 1.1, 2.1,
0.2, 1.2, 2.2
];
let YData1 = B
| summarize Data = make_set(YData1), YName = 'YData1';
let YData2 = B
| summarize Data = make_set(YData2), YName = 'YData2';
let BTemp = union YData1, YData2;
A
| join kind=leftouter (BTemp) on YName
| project-away *1
```

| XName | YName | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XData | YData1 | [1, 1.1, 1.2] |
| XData | YData2 | [2, 2.1, 2.2] |

Comment: Thanks for the answer; unfortunately this doesn't really accomplish what I'm looking for. I'm trying to do this as part of a query chain, programmatically, based on the data in `A`. Having to split out the `YData1` and `YData2` queries in this way, specifying them by name in the code, defeats the purpose.